# Moving WP from /blog to root directory

Tags: directory

I'm moving a WordPress installation from /blog to the root directory on the server.

There weren't more than ten blog posts in the blog, but I'm concerned about Google finding dead urls.

Is there an easy way to handle redirects?  A plugin, etc.  Or a simple best practice?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this plugin can work for you: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Check this Codex article:

> #### [Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)
>
> On the `Settings->General` screen in a single site installation of WordPress, there are two fields named "WordPress address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)". These are also known as the "Home" and "Site URL" settings. They are important settings, since they control where WordPress thinks your site is located. They control the display of the URL in the admin section of your page as well as the front end, and are used throughout the WordPress code.
>
> - The "Home" setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.
> - The "Site URL" setting is the address where your WordPress core files reside.